# Getting a subnet range from an entered IP that reads off an excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, ip, console-application, subnet

I have a program where I enter an IP in I get the hostname. I have an excel sheet imported with thousands of subnet ranges, and what I am trying to do with them is upon entering the IP it looks through the spreadsheet, get's the closest match and prints out that whole row and column of the spreadsheet to the console. I have a test code that prints out the very first row, but that's it.

So at the end of the program it prints, the ip, host, and everything in that row. I have everything except for it to be able to search for the range.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Investigations
{
    class Program
    {





        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;
            string str;


            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address: " + addr);
            Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + entry.HostName);


            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\ipsheet.xlxs");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Excel.Range firstFind = null;
            Excel.XlFindLookIn xlValues;
            Excel.XlLookAt xlPart;
```

Comment: Show us the test code, example input, example output, example data...

Comment: There is the code, just updated it. Outputs just the host and ip at this moment

Comment: You may have a c# expert on SO who doesn't have a clue what a host IP or a subnet range is, but would know how to fix your code. Never assume knowledge, examples are good!

Comment: It's matching an ip address closest to the ipaddress in the A1 column in my excel sheet, then printing that whole row. 

So for example. 8.8.8.8 In the spreadsheet would match to the closest to that ie. 8.8.8.7

Comment: Subnet is how many addresses can be on a host address (servers are hosts) so they will have a range up until a certain amount of bits so for my code 8.8.8.8 would match up to 8.8.8.8/24 on the sheet or the closest ip.

Comment: So for someone who doesn't understand that, its matching lets say 10 to the row that has the value 10, and if there is no row, the closes value in a block in that row to 10, so it could be 9, 8, 7, 6 etc.

Comment: When you're on your third consecutive comment, consider whether it should instead just be a structured edit. See the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for more clarity.

Comment: I have just the excel sheet imported, and my ipaddress value printed, I don't know if it can get any simpler than that.